# Advice: flatiron, formidable and aws s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, flatiron.js, formidable

I'm new with serverside programming with node.js. I'm sticking together a tiny webapp with it right now and having the usual startup learning to do. The following piece of code *WORKS*. But I would love to know if it's more or less a right way to do a simple file upload from a form and throw it into aws s3:

```
app.router.post('/form', { stream: true }, function () {

    var req = this.req,
        res = this.res,
        form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form
    .parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log('Parsed file upload' + err);
        if (err) {
            res.end('error: Upload failed: ' + err);
        } else {
            var img = fs.readFileSync(files.image.path);
            var data = {
                Bucket: 'le-bucket',
                Key:    files.image.name,
                Body:   img
            };
            s3.client.putObject(data, function() {
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
            });
            res.end('success: Uploaded file(s)');
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I had to turn buffer off in union / flatiron.plugins.http.

What I would like to learn is, when to stream load a file and when to syncload it. It will be a really tiny webapp with little traffic.

If it's more or less good then please consider this as a token of working code which I also would throw into a gist. It's not that easy to find documenation and working examples of this kind of stuff. I like flatiron alot. But it's small module approach leads to lots of splattered docs and examples all over the net, speak alone of tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You should use other module than formidable because as far as I know formidable does not have s3 storage option , then you must save the files in your server before uploading it.
I would recommend you to use : [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty)

Use this [example](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/blob/master/examples/s3.js) in order to upload directly to S3 without saving it locally in your server.